# Oracle SQL plus

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I am a complete beginner in Oracle Database.I have installed Oracle Database 11g R2 11.2.0.1.0 for Windows 7 64bit. I need Oracle SQL plus to run and execute sql queries.Please tell me which link to download and help me to install it and set up. I have searched many forums but could'nt find it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://softadvice.informer.com/Oracle_Sql_Plus_8.0_Free_Download.html

Comment: not a programming question

Comment: agreed, not a programming question, but the close reason everyone's picked is also incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlplus command line client comes with Oracle database installation package and installs by default on the same machine you installed Oracle. You can install Oracle client on any other client machine that will connect to the Oracle server. Oracle client will have network layer and utils to connect to oracle and sqlplus. You can also install a graphical client called SQL Developer - it's a Java based GUI client available as a separate download from Oracle website.